# Armadillo getting undefined reference for shared lapack library

Tags: c++, linker-errors, dynamic-linking, armadillo, lapack

I have compiled BLAS and LAPACK library using gcc in ubuntu 18.4 LTS. The **static libraries are working well** with Armadillo headers but the **shared lapack library is getting error** with 28 undefined references of blas functions which I presume are "**Extra Precise BLAS routines**". I don't know if I made something wrong with the build of lapack shared library?! The linking errors of armadillo are as follows:

```
g++  -o ../../lib/Debug/numlib ../../lib/Debug/src/arma_test_1.o ../../lib/Debug/src/blas_test.o ../../lib/Debug/src/cmatrix_test.o ../../lib/Debug/src/main.o   ../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so ../../lib/Debug/libblas.so ../../../../../../../usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libgfortran.a ../../../../../../../usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libquadmath.a

../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_sgemv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zgemv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_cgbmv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_cgbmv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_chemv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_csymv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_sgbmv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_dgemv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zsymv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_csymv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_ssymv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_ssymv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zgemv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_dsymv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zhemv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zgbmv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_sgemv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_chemv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_dgemv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_cgemv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_sgbmv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zgbmv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_dgbmv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zhemv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_zsymv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_dsymv_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_dgbmv2_x_'
../../lib/Debug/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `blas_cgemv_x_'
```

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

It is very specific about armadillo+Lapack(shared library built from netlib's LAPACK src..) ... I want to know the possible source of these BLAS routines which are not available in netlib's BLAS and LAPACK!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: My question is very specific about armadillo+Lapack(shared library built from netlib's LAPACK src..) ... I am expecting an answer regarding the possible source of these BLAS routines which are not available in netlib's BLAS and LAPACK packages!

Answer (score 0):

XBLAS need to be integrated..  Details can be found in the following link.

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1730

Comment: Unfortunately that link has since gone offline, and it looks like even wayback doesn't have it.  What was discussed at that URL?  I end up with the same undefined symbols problem (I have xblas installed, but it includes symbols without the extra trailing underscore, e.g. blas_sgemv_x not blas_sgemv_x_)